# Google Developer Account Terminated: What to do?

Tags: android, google-play

So we just launched a beta closed test, and our account was completely terminated. I believe the reason was a deceptive name.

[image]

We filed an appeal, but we're not sure what to do next. We had no idea our name was violating anything, and if this appeal doesn't go through, we have to publish this app. We some big financial backers, and getting the account terminated completely was kind of a shock to all of us.

So, what to do next, if the appeal doesn't go through? Should we make a new account, and republish the app? Should I contact someone and tell them I just need to change the name? We're kind of freaking out here.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Please write an email to  googleplay-developer-support@google.com

Ask if they can reactivate your account with changing the name to resolve the issue.  Otherwise sure you can pay 25€ to register a new developer account if that is an option for you.

Make sure your developer name (and your apps) are not deceptive, check if your app description matches to their actual features, check if your app and developer names are already used (simply google the names) and if you feel like it it is always a good idea to check copyright and name brands. (Trademark checks)

If you want to do a trademark check it is a good idea to consult a lawyer, however you can do a simple trademark check yourself which is almost always enough for a small android publisher. Go to a trademark research site for your region, for example UK and EU https://trademarks.ipo.gov.uk/ipo-tmtext . I can recommend to search for "text" and "contains any" to get the best results. For example text="adidas" contains-any in clothing will return that it is already registered, therefore you shouldn't call a fashion app "adidas" or a deceptive version like "adi-das" or alike.

Answer (score 0):

Same here in US region. I used a name that's not a trademark or anything. It took them 2 months (which's supposed to be "Up to 7 days") to get back to me saying they won't reactivate my account. I've tried to appeal and reach their customer service (it shows "server error" on online chat and the online help page is a dead end too). You may seek a legal assistance to get their attention.